# Get data from htmlService Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm trying to display data from an HTMLService form in an ui.alert.
I tried alternative solutions, none of which seem to work I'm out of ideas at this point, I don't understand why the code isn't working…

(Script is container bound)

AppScript:

```
function showCustomOrder() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('CustomOrderHTML')
  .evaluate()
  .setWidth(1000)
  .setHeight(700);
  ui.showModalDialog(html, ' Bestellung');
}
 
 
function processForm(formObject) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(formObject))
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(JSON.stringify(formObject))
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    
    <div class="modalbody">

        <div class="divider"></div>

            <div class="modalwrapper">
            
                <form class="inputformwrapper" id="customOrderForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google.script.run.processForm(this)">

                    <div class="inputblockwrapper">
                        <div class="labelwrapper">
                            <label class="requiredlabel" for="orderName">Produktname</label>
                        </div>

                        <input class="inputfield" 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Gib den Namen deines Wunschartikels ein..." 
                            id="orderName"
                            name="orderName"
                            required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="confirmbuttonwrapper">
                        <input class="confirmbutton" 
                            type="submit" 
                            value="Absenden"  
                            id="orderSubmit">
                    </div>

                </form>

        </div>

    </div>

  </body>
```

UPDATE:
I'm malding right now,
for some reason, this code doesn't work in Safari & Firefox.
I ran the code from the same sheet in chrome, works just fine…
If anyone has a clue why this code isn't cross browser compatible, I'd really appreciate some input.

This is the error form I get from Safari when submitting the form:

```
[Error] Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GSzlzj7nHPIUt-RIJfsPFobtnLbuoXedtJk1x11BdT0/edit#gid=608101151' from frame with URL 'https://n-5knwkifokitvy7ttzpxm4675zp3t23b2pntbdhy-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' flag is not set and navigation is not triggered by user activation.
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Check if there are message on the web browser console and on the executions logs. If so, please add them textually into the question body.

Comment: In showCustomOrder() where is ui defined?

Comment: Also not sure about your onsubmit. I don’t think it’s a script, but a callback function.

Comment: @Rubén added both (sry for pastebin im lazy)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please bear in mind that question on this site should be self contained. Considering this, please add the relevant parts of the linked resources directly into the question body.

Comment: By the way, please test your script using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled and sign in only with the account that you use for the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ok course you have to define ui. For example SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(), where SpreadsheetApp.getUi() returns a Ui object.

Comment: It was defined outside the function, there you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
function showCustomOrder() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah2').setWidth(1000).setHeight(700);
  ui.showModelessDialog(html, 'Title');
}
 
function processForm(formObject) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(formObject))
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(JSON.stringify(formObject))
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="modalbody">
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="modalwrapper">
      <form class="inputformwrapper" id="customOrderForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google.script.run.processForm(this)">
        <div class="inputblockwrapper">
          <div class="labelwrapper">
            <label class="requiredlabel" for="orderName">Produktname</label>
          </div>
          <input class="inputfield" type="text" placeholder="Gib den Namen deines Wunschartikels ein..." id="orderName" name="orderName" required>
        </div>
        <div class="confirmbuttonwrapper">
          <input class="confirmbutton" type="submit" value="Absenden" id="orderSubmit/">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Form after getting filled out:

[image]

The Alert:

[image]

Comment: Thx, works but only in chrome.